# Ambari/Nagios overwrites hadoop-services.cfg file on startup

Tags: hadoop

When I shut down Nagios from the Ambari Web UI, modify the file `hadoop-services.cfg`, save it and open it, new settings are there.

However, when I start the Nagios again (from the Ambari Web UI) and open the file `hadoop-services.cfg`, changes are lost.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I saw somewhere that a template (which Ambari uses to generate hadoop-services.cfg file) is located in:

```
/var/lib/ambari-agent/puppet/modules/hdp-nagios/templates/
```

However, I do not have the folder "puppet" and everything after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to stop nagios service from command line, using:

```
service nagios stop
```

instead of doing it from the Ambari Web UI. Then the changes to the `hadoop-services.cfg` should be made and finally the nagios service should be started again using

```
service nagios start
```

Afterwards, changes are persisted.